# Combine character matrices into one

Tags: r, matrix

Given two matrices

```
a <- matrix(c("a","","","d"),2,2)
b <- matrix(c("","b","",""),2,2)

a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  ""  
[2,] ""   "d" 
b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] ""   ""  
[2,] "b"  ""
```

Is there an easy way to combine these two into one and get

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"   ""  
[2,] "b"  "d"
```

without looping over each individual element?

I am interested in the problem of this "merge" in general. However, for the time being, each cell is non-empty in only one of those matrices (i.e., the case where cell `[1,1]` contains something in matrix `a` and in matrix `b` is ruled out).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If two matrices are of same dimension we can do :

```
ifelse(a == '', b, a)

#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "a"  ""  
#[2,] "b"  "d"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
a[a == "" & b != ""] <- b[b != ""]
a
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  ""  
[2,] "b"  "d"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use. `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
case_when(a== '' ~ b, TRUE ~ a)
```